# Deadlock on communicating with multiple children

Tags: pipe, ipc, deadlock

This is a followup to the [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219905/31443):

I have a `parent.py`:

```
from sys import argv
from random import randrange
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
lines = int(argv[1])
procs = int(argv[2])
cmd = ["python", "child.py"]
children = list()
for p in range(procs):
  children.append([0,Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)])
for i in range(lines):
    child = children[randrange(procs)]
    child[0] += 1
    child[1].stdin.write("hello\n")
for n,p in children:
    p.stdin.close()
    out = p.stdout.read()
    p.stdout.close()
    exitcode = p.wait()
    print n,out,exitcode
    assert n == int(out)
assert lines == sum(n for n,_ in children)
```

and a `child.py`:

```
import sys
l = list()
for line in sys.stdin:
   l.append(line)
sys.stdout.write(str(len(l)))
```

When I create a single child, it works fine:

```
$ python parent.py 100 1
100 100 0
```

However, multiple children deadlock:

```
$ python parent.py 100 2 &
[1] 59492
$ strace -p 59492
Process 59492 attached - interrupt to quit
read(5, ^C <unfinished ...>
Process 59492 detached
$ pstree -p 59492
python(59492)-+-python(59494)
              `-python(59495)
$ strace -p 59494
Process 59494 attached - interrupt to quit
read(0, ^C <unfinished ...>
Process 59494 detached
$ strace -p 59495
Process 59495 attached - interrupt to quit
read(0, ^C <unfinished ...>
Process 59495 detached
```

**Why do children continue to `read()` even after I close their `stdin`?**

PS. The simple change of closing **all** children's stdins **before** reading from any of them **solves** the problem:

```
$ python parent.py 10000 4
2486 2486 0
2493 2493 0
2531 2531 0
2490 2490 0
```

**WHY?!**

Comment: `python parent.py 100 2` works for me, every time.

Comment: @Celada: you are using python 2.7, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using, 2.7.3.

Comment: Do you mean "***Note*** that the simple change of ..."?

Comment: @G-Man: YES!! fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Python **2.6**

Python **2.7** does *not* deadlock.

Comment: @Celada: looks like it, but the bug says that it should not be fixed in 2.7 - and my problem does not manifest itself in 2.7, so I am not sure.

Comment: Oh yeah, I misread that as *will* backport to 2.7 instead of *won't* backport to 2.7. So indeed it must be some other bug.

Answer (score 0):

You've programmed your children to read ALL stdin (`for line in sys.stdin:`), that is, to keep reading until they reach EOF. If their `stdin` is a pipe, they will get EOF when the other end of the pipe closes.

Comment: Yes, but the parent *does* close the other end of the pipe: you've got `for n,p in children: p.stdin.close()`. What are the OP and I missing?

Comment: @Celada I guess that he wasn't closing the pipe originally and it deadlocked. Now he fixed it and he's asking why closing the pipe solves the deadlock.

Comment: No, your interpretation of my question is completely off the mark,

Comment: @sds OK. I have only 2.7 and 3.* in my system's repos. But it's weird if this were  a python bug.  (I mean this should be about some rather straightforward gluing of python code to the system functions). In any case, I'm glad you figured it out.